# UITableView cell gives different widths. How to solve this?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the function `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate the height of the cell having two textfields of dynamic text

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.kkCellIdentifier) as! NibTableViewCell
    cell.updateConstraints()
    let width = cell.contentView.frame.width
    //use width to calculate the height
}
```

I am running this on iPhone 6 simulator.

In portrait:

I get cell width sometimes as 375 (wrong- it is actually tableView's frame width) and sometimes as 320 (Correct one)

In Landscape:

I get cell width sometimes as 320 and sometimes as 659 (Correct one)

Why is it like this? Is this a bug?

How to solve this?

Comment: One could be to use `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NibTableViewCell` instead of `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.kkCellIdentifier) as! NibTableViewCell`

Comment: I'm pretty sure 375 is the correct width for the 6... 320 is the correct with for the 5 and 4...

Comment: @nhgrif 375 is actually the total frame size of table view. 320 is the actual cell's content width, because of the indents it puts on the right and left side of the screen for better visibility.

And I got crash with error (lldb)  by doing `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NibTableViewCell`

Comment: That's because the cell at that index path isn't a `NibTableViewCell` (or there is nothing at that index path at all).

Comment: @nhgrif I get it. `NibTableViewCell` is loaded from a nib. It is not a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The `Frame` of your a `UITableViewCell` will be set after the call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so initially the frame if you have `Nib` for your custom cell might be by default 320, if you are doing it programmatically it might be zero. I do recommend you to use `Autolayout` to set the constraints of your custom `UITableViewCell` this can be done using both `Interface Builder` and programmatically. Here is the [Apple's guide to Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I am using autolayout for the tableViewCell through Interfacebuilder.